# Recursive array set with method

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way to set an array recursively? something along these lines:

```
  $array = new ArrayElements ( ) ;
  $array->set('index', 10)->set('indexInIndex',20);
```

and then the array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [index] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [indexInIndex] => 20
        )

)
```

I know it must involve a fluid interface, but the gist of it is how to tell if a method was chained to a method 'set' and then take the index to the previous set setou, and write on top of this index

`func_get_args` may also have a close and grab all the parameters and set in accordance with the thread, something like

```
      public function set ( $index , $value ) {
         if ( func_num_args() > 2 ) {
            $indexes = array_splice ( func_get_args() , 2 ) ;
         }
      }
```

Then ..

```
->set( 'index' , 'value' , 'inIndex' , 'inIndex1' )
```

would be equal to: `$storage [ 'inIndex' ] [ 'inIndex1' ] [ 'index' ] = 'value' ;`

Comment: Your set method is behaving inconsistently. Also, whats wrong with just using `$array['index']['foo']` or `$array['index'] = array(10)`

Comment: no, I'm just looking at whether there is any way to do this by using methods

Comment: It probably is. But it's ugly and no one with a sane mind would want to use it, so why bother? Do it the regular and standard way. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resulting array structures and argument orders seem odd to me. I wonder if if maybe your sample outputs are just mistakes. Maybe this helps you achieve your goal.

```
$r = array(array_pop($args));
foreach (array_reverse($indexes) as $index) {
    $r = array($index => $r);
}
```

then

```
'a' , 'b' , 'c', 'val'
```

yields

```
$r['a']['b']['c'] = 'val';
```